# Objects showing null when importing and deserializing

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Currently passing a `HashMap<byte[],byte[]>` where both values are there prior serialization within the `TMap`, visible in the `FILEPATH`, whilst the program is running, shows the keys and values. I've tried changing it to a non static field but alas, when loading the `TMap` on the constructor of the object the `Map` holds `null`. Here's the code used to save and load the `TMap`. Has anyone got any suggestions?

```
public void loadTMap() {
    HashMap<byte[], byte[]> TMap = new HashMap<>();
    File f = new File("FILEPATH);
    if(f.exists()) {
      try {
         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("FILEPATH");
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
         TMap = (HashMap<byte[], byte[]>) in.readObject();
         in.close();
         fileIn.close();
      } catch (IOException i) {
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
      }
}
}

public void saveTMap(HashMap<byte[], byte[]> TMap) {
      try {
         FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(FILEPATH);
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
         out.writeObject(TMap);
         out.close();
         fileOut.close();
      } catch (IOException i) {
         i.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Comment: Maybe, the method `loadTMap()` should return the loaded map.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `TMap` is written and read correctly. The problem is that you can not use a byte array as key for the map as `equals` compares the reference of the byte array and not the contents.

Wrap your key in custom class and implement `equals` and `hashCode` like this:

```
public class ByteArrayKey implements Serializable {

    private byte[] content;

    public ByteArrayKey(byte[] content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ByteArrayKey that = (ByteArrayKey) o;
        return Arrays.equals(content, that.content);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(content);
    }
}
```

Then change you load and save methods like this:

```
public static HashMap<ByteArrayKey, byte[]> loadTMap() {
    HashMap<ByteArrayKey, byte[]> TMap = new HashMap<>();
    File f = new File(FILEPATH);
    if (f.exists()) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(FILEPATH);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            TMap = (HashMap<ByteArrayKey, byte[]>) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            c.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return TMap;
}

public static void saveTMap(HashMap<ByteArrayKey, byte[]> TMap) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(FILEPATH);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(TMap);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```